# How do I use omniauth in RoR to extract Facebook birthday information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with Omniauth 1.3.1.  When someone logs into my app using Facebook, I’d like to record their birthday, however, I can’t figure out how to extract it from Facebook’s site when I got my auth object.  I have this in my config/initializers/omniauth.rb file …

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    …   

  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           scope: 'public_profile', info_fields: 'id,email,link,birthday,first_name,last_name'
```

but once my callback is returned to my application ..

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
```

The call dies because there is no birthday to extract …

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  puts "extra: #{auth.extra}" 
  bday = Date.strptime(auth.extra.raw_info.birthday,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

What is printed out in “extra:” is

```
extra: #<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash first_name=“MyName” id="1777736954079999” last_name=“LastName” link="https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1777736954079999/">>
```

even though I definitely have a birthday set up in my Facebook profile.  What else do I need to do to pass/extract the birthday information?

Comment: try adding `user_birthday` to scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with Facebook's Login [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile), the permission for `public_profile` doesn't include birthday information, but only the following fields: `id, name, first_name, last_name, age_range, link, gender, locale, picture, timezone, updated_time, verified`.

The `user_birthday` permission will give you access to date and month of a person's birthday. They also state that it may or may not include the year.

Try adding `user_birthday` to your scope.

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
       scope: 'public_profile,user_birthday', info_fields: 'id,email,link,birthday,first_name,last_name'
```